# Reading PSD file format

Tags: c#, photoshop, file-format

I wonder if this is even possible. I have an application that adds a context menu when you right click a file. It all works fine but here is what I'd like to do:

If the file is a PSD then I want the program to extract the image. Is this possible to do without having Photoshop installed?

Basically I want the user to right click and click "image" which would save a .jpg of the file for them.

edit: will be using c#
Thanks

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/skimpt/ If you checkout/browse the code, look in the Platters folder. So Platters > classes > photoshop. Its been a couple of years since i worked on that project so you are going to have to go through it

Comment: i found it: 
` if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filename) == ".psd") {                        Photoshop.PsdFile psd = new Photoshop.PsdFile(); 
psd.Load(filename);
                        //decode the image
                        Image myPsdImage = Photoshop.ImageDecoder.DecodeImage(psd);
                        //create new image
                        skImage ski = new skImage(myPsdImage);
                        Common.ShowToastForm(ski);
                    }

Comment: Also: https://github.com/NtreevSoft/psd-parser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For people who are reading this now: the link from accepted answer doesn't seem to work anymore (at least for me). Would add a comment there, but not allowed to comment yet - hence I'm adding a new answer.

The working link where you can find the psdplugin code for Paint.Net: https://github.com/PsdPlugin/PsdPlugin

Answer (score 20):

The [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) libraries (which provide [bindings for C#](http://midimick.com/magicknet/)) also support the PSD format. They might be easier to get started with than getting into the Paint.NET code and also come with a quite free (BSD-like) license.

A simple sample (found at [http://midimick.com/magicknet/magickDoc.html)](http://midimick.com/magicknet/magickDoc.html) using MagickNet would look like this:

```
using System;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MagickNet.Magick.Init();
    MagicNet.Image img = new MagicNet.Image("file.psd");
    img.Resize(System.Drawing.Size(100,100));
    img.Write("newFile.png");
    MagickNet.Magick.Term();
}
```

Note: MagickNet has moved to http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/ImageMagick_in_VBNET.aspx

Comment: its `MagickNet.Image img = new MagickNet.Image("file.psd");` and `img.Resize(new System.Drawing.Size(100,100));`

Answer (score 17):

Well, there's a PSD plugin for Paint.NET which I think is Open-Source which you might want to take a look at for starters:

http://frankblumenberg.de/doku/doku.php?id=paintnet:psdplugin#download

Answer (score 3):

This guy do it easier:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/simplepsd.aspx

With a C# library and a sample project.

I've tried with PS2 files and works ok.

Answer (score 3):

I have written a PSD parser which extracts raster format layers from all versions of PSD and PSB. http://www.telegraphics.com.au/svn/psdparse/trunk

Answer (score 3):

You can use [GroupDocs.Viewer for .NET](https://products.groupdocs.com/viewer/net) API to render your PSD files as images (JPG, PNG, BMP) in your application using a few lines of code.

**C#**

```
ViewerConfig config = new ViewerConfig();
config.StoragePath = "D:\\storage\\";

// Create handler
ViewerImageHandler imageHandler = new ViewerImageHandler(config);

// Guid implies that unique document name 
string guid = "sample.psd";

// Get document pages as images
List<PageImage> pages = imageHandler.GetPages(guid);

foreach (PageImage page in pages)
{
    // Access each image using page.Stream
}
```

For more details and sample code, please visit [here](https://docs.groupdocs.com/display/viewernet/Rendering+of+the+Documents+as+Image).
*Disclosure: I work as a Developer Evangelist at GroupDocs.*

Comment: Links are fine, but please consider posting the relevant code from those links to help answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my own psd parser and exporter:
http://papirosnik.info/psdsplit/.
 It allows to correctly parse psd with rgb color 8, 16- and 32-bit for channel, process user masks, export selected layers into jpeg, png, jng, bmp, tiff; create xml layout of exported layers and groups and also create a texture atlas and animations set from given layers.
It's entirely written in C#. If you want its sources inform me via support link on About dialog in the application.

Answer (score 1):

ImageMagick.NET - http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/ - is the later version of the link 0xA3 gave, with some slightly different syntax.  (Note, this is untested):

```
using ImageMagickNET;

public void Test() {
        MagickNet.InitializeMagick();
        ImageMagickNET.Image img = new ImageMagickNET.Image("file.psd");
        img.Resize(new Geometry(100, 100, 0, 0, false, false);
        img.Write("newFile.png");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got extraction from psd working.  see my answer here

[How to extract layers from a Photoshop file? C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499597/how-to-extract-layers-from-a-photoshop-file-c-sharp/14438310#14438310)

may help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

FastStone does this pretty efficiently.
They do not have their libraries availaible, but I guess you can contact them and see if they can help.

Check out their website: http://www.faststone.org/download.htm

Answer (score 0):

I've had great success with Aspose's Imaging component which can load and save PSD files without Photoshop: https://products.aspose.com/imaging/net