# How to extract layers from a Photoshop file? C#

Tags: c#, photoshop

Is there a library in C# that will allow me to read the layers in a photoshop file (PSD) and extract them as transparent images (PNG)?

Photoshop has a batch command that will extract all layers in individual files but there is no choice of transparent PNGs. My goal is to create a small utility program that will create combinations of layers as you like (for example think of creating a card deck).

Answer (score 4):

There's a nice [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/PSDParser.aspx) on CodeProject which might be helpful. And here's a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414852/reading-psd-file-format) on SO discussing PSD file format parsing with C#.

Comment: The SO discussion only talks about reading a photoshop file (so do the links). Unfortunately, the demo application in CodeProject article doesn't work with new CS3 formats. :(

Answer (score 4):

I couldnt find much on this anywhere, but this is how i ended up doing it.

```
using Photoshop;

Photoshop.PsdFile psd = new Photoshop.PsdFile();
psd.Load(pingTextsPsd);

for (int j = 0; j < psd.Layers.Count; j++)
            {
                System.Drawing.Image myPsdImage = ImageDecoder.DecodeImage(psd.Layers[j]);

                myPsdImage.Save(pingsOutputPath + psd.Layers[j].Name + ".png");

            }
```

i had to downloaded the cs files that Mr Frank Blumenberg did (based on the Endogine engine by Jonas Beckeman), as getting the paintdotnet dll itself wasnt enough.

I believe it was here that i got the cs files.

http://code.google.com/p/skimpt/source/browse/trunk/Skimpt3/Skimpt3/classes/photoshop/?r=72

This should allow you to get the layers..

:-)

This seems to work fine with CS6 files too.

update: a vs2013 website is here: http://goo.gl/H6nWSN.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with Photoshop COM.

Comment: See in particular this article (http://www.pcpix.com/Photoshop/) on accessing the COM interface from .NET.

Answer (score 1):

I found a [code sample](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/DecodesaPhotoShoppsdfileintooneormoreframes.htm) that does this in Java.

```
"Supports uncompressed or RLE-compressed RGB files only"
```

Also supports only older PSD versions :

```
"Does not support additional features in PS versions higher than 3.0"
```

Also ImageMagick handles PSD and has interfaces to many languages :

```
"Choose from these interfaces: G2F (Ada), MagickCore (C), MagickWand (C), ChMagick (Ch), ImageMagickObject (COM+), Magick++ (C++), JMagick (Java), L-Magick (Lisp), NMagick (Neko/Haxe), MagickNet (.NET), PascalMagick (Pascal), PerlMagick (Perl), MagickWand for PHP (PHP), IMagick (PHP), PythonMagick (Python), RMagick (Ruby), or TclMagick (Tcl/TK)"
```

Answer (score 1):

ImagicMagick (which *was* mentioned in the other SO article) does allow layers to be extracted separately.   See: http://www.rubblewebs.co.uk/imagemagick/psd.php

You can try this for yourself using the command line tool:

```
convert boots.psd[0] -thumbnail 340x340 boots_png.png
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have Photoshop installed, then you may want to look at the code at http://frankblumenberg.de/doku/doku.php?id=paintnet:psdplugin for more sample code that loads PSD files.

Unfortunately, I don't know of a pre-existing PNG library that does what you want but the canonical library code for PNG file manipulation is located at http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/.