# What graphic format can I use for layers?

Tags: c#, image, pdf, layer, psd

I need to be able to take multiple images and save them to a file that can then be read by a graphics program like Photoshop or Illustrator and edited.  I need to be able to do this in a C#/.Net environment.  It looks like PDF's have the capabilities to do layers but I am not sure if any of the free components like PDFSharp will support the layers.  It would be nice to be able to write directly to a Photoshop file (PSD) but I haven't found anything that can do that.  Any other suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There was a question here on [reading PSD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414852/reading-psd-file-format), there answer was to use [Paint.NET open source PSD plugin](http://frankblumenberg.de/doku/doku.php?id=paintnet:psdplugin#download)

Answer (score 0):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) Should be useful for what you're going for.

PSD is Photoshop's format and supports layers
XCF also supports layers and is for GIMP

I know Fireworks uses PNG with layers but I know a lot of other editors don't support it.