# How I can get out files from Photoshop in C#?

Tags: c#, photoshop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading PSD file format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414852/reading-psd-file-format)

Is there a library in C# that will allow me to read the layers in a photoshop file (PSD) and extract them as transparent images (PNG)?

Photoshop has a batch command that will extract all layers in individual files but there is no choice of transparent PNGs. My goal is to create a small utility program that will create combinations of layers as you like (for example think of creating a card deck).

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/PSDParser.aspx) on CodeProject which might be helpful. And here's a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414852/reading-psd-file-format) on SO discussing PSD file format parsing with C#.